# Trying to remove characters of string B from string A in standard C

Tags: c, string

So if *A*="a***B***c***D***e***F***g" and *B*="***BDF***", the output should be "aceg".

My idea was to check one-by-one if character of *A* is equal with any character of *B* (*A*[0] vs *B*[0]/*B*[1]...*B*[n] and so on). Therefore if they do not match, a counter variable is incremented. If the counter is smaller than length of *B*, then this character is deleted and when the counter equals length of *B*, the character is moved in an other string.

My version looks like this, but is not working:

```
void remove_characters(char s[], char r[])
{
    int k, i, j, l = 0;
    char s_copy[20];

    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++){
        for (j = 0; r[j] != '\0'; j++)
            if (s[i] != r[j])
                k++;
        if (k = strlen(r)){
            s_copy[l++] = s[i];
            k = 0;
        }
    }
    puts(s_copy);
}

void main()
{
    char s1[20],s2[20];
    printf("Enter the first string: ");
    gets(s1);
    printf("Enter the second string: ");
    gets(s2);
    remove_characters(s1,s2);
}
```

Any ideas where is the problem?

Comment: `if (k = strlen(r))` is very likely a bug, an assignment doesn't make sense here

Comment: Do basic debugging. Run your program in a debugger and trace it as it runs. [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: Please tell us more details about "is not working". Show a few examples of input, actual output and expected output. Is the order of the characters in `B` relevant? Would you expect the same result with e.g. `A="aDcBeFg"` and `B="BDF"` or `A="aBcBeBg"` and `B="BDF"`? Please [edit] your question to add requested information, don't use comments for this purpose.

Comment: Unrelated but: 1. `gets` is terribly unsafe, deprecated for decades and should just never be used and 2. having *magic length* (**`20`** in char `s_copy[20];` is bad practice because it makes the function code hard to reuse.

Comment: Your loops for `i` and `j` look like you're on the right path.  What you're doing with `k`, though, looks wrong... It looks like it should be a boolean initialized just inside your `i` loop, set inside the `if` in the `j` loop, then checked as the condition in the `if` following the `j` loop rather than assigning the string length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Any ideas where is the problem?

There's more than one.

- UnholySheep mentioned `if (k = strlen(r))`; you meant `==` rather than `=`.
- `k` is not initialized before use; this is to be done before the inner loop.
- `s_copy` is not null terminated.

Here's an alternative implementation which utilizes the standard function `strchr` and modifies `s`, which has the advantages that no limit is imposed on the length of `s` and that the result is available to the caller rather than just printed:

```
void remove_characters(char s[], char r[])
{
    char *t = s;
    do  if (*s && strchr(r, *s)) continue;
        else *t++ = *s;
      while (*s++);
}
```

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers, all of them helped me a lot.